# WPF MVVM one view multiple object types

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, mvvm, observablecollection

Currently I'm learning WPF with MVVM and have maybe a crazy idea...

I have several simple classes:

```
public class Car : IProduct
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Brand {get;set;}
  // some custom properies
}
public class Seat : IProduct
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Brand {get;set;}
  // some custom properties
}
```

Idea was that I have one editor view for diferent models.

```
public class ProductViewModel<T> : ViewModelBase, IProductViewModel<T> where T : IProduct
  {
    private T m_editorModel;
    public T EditorModel
    {
      get { return m_editorModel; }
      set
      {
        m_editorModel = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => EditorModel);
      }
    }

    public Type ModelType
    {
      get { return typeof(T); }
    }
  }
```

Which can be afterwords set to view DataContext

```
 viewModel = ViewModelFactory.CreateViewModel<IProductViewModel<Car>>();
 view = ViewFactory.CreateView<ProductView>();
 view.DataContext = viewModel;
 // etc...
```

The problem is that I don't know is it possible or how to create in run time 
ObservableCollection of same object EditorModel.

Is it maybe easier path to create for each class it's own view and viewmodel or something totally different?

Comment: Do you mean adding an ObservableCollection<T> into your ProductViewModel<T> class? Is your problem related to the fact your potiential ObservableCollection would contain different kind of objects but bound to the same control?

Comment: Yes. The ObservableCollection<T> should afterwords be visible in some listview control. Maybe I was tired I did not notice I can do `public ObservableCollection<T> SomeModels = new ObservableCollection<T>();`. Now to bind them to view ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVVM in general [I'm not speaking for everyone here], you don't want to be instantiating views from code. Instead we work with and manipulate data. To change views, we change view models and often set the connections between the two in simple `DataTemplate`s:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
    <Views:MainView />
</DataTemplate>
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:UsersViewModel}">
    <Views:UsersView />
</DataTemplate>
```

This way, we don't need to explicitly set any `DataContext`s. We can simply have a `BaseViewModel` property that each view model extends:

```
public BaseViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return viewModel; }
    set { if (viewModel != value) { viewModel = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ViewModel"); } }
}
```

We can change view models and therefore views like this:

```
ViewModel = new UsersView();
```

Then we can display the relating view in a `ContentControl` like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

Finally, in my opinion, you really should create a view model for each view... the view model's sole job is to provide the data and functionality for each view. So unless you have multiple identical views, you'd need different view models. It *is* however possible to have one view model that all of the views bind to, but I'd advise against that for large applications.

Comment: At the end this is the way i went. Thanks